# Problems embedding a Power BI Report into MVC Application

Tags: powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

We have developed a report using Microsoft Power BI Desktop (optimized for Report Server) Version: 2.76.5678.1521 64-bit (January, 2020).
This report is hosted on Microsoft Power BI Report Server Version 15.0.1102.759 (January 2020).

We are attempting to embed this report in an MVC application written in C# in Visual Studio 2017. We are using the following script:

```
    <iframe style="width:100%; height:450px;"
    src="http://myserver.local/PBIReports/powerbi/Folder/My%20Report%20Name?
    rs:embed=true" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

It works in Firefox and Chrome. In Internet Explorer he gets a blank screen and in Edge he gets a “Can’t Reach This Page Error”. Any advice or suggestions on how to resolve this in IE and Edge would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you load `http://myserver.local/PBIReports/powerbi/Folder/My%20Report%20Name?rs:embed=true` directly in each browser?

Comment: Also, the above code has spaces & linebreaks in the iframe tag, are they present in your real code?

Comment: If I load the URL as listed above then the report successfully runs in the browser. In the real code there are no linebreaks but there are spaces. Where should the spaces be removed?